# What is the correct term for a joint stabilized by three points of articulation?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, terminology, linkage, biomechanics

I am trying to find the correct term for this mechanical principle. I have a biomechanical system where two objects are anchored to each other along three points of articulation. These points are arranged in a parallel line along the mediolateral axis (in blue) and are perpendicular to the anteroposterior axis (in green). Because of the orientation of these three points, the joint is essentially incapable of rotating along the mediolateral axis (no yaw).

[image]

I had remembered hearing that having three points of articulation is considered ideal when the desired function is to restrict freedom of motion at that joint as much as possible. However, I cannot remember what the precise term for this mechanical principle is called. I thought it was called “three points of articulation/contact”, but when I looked this up elsewhere on the Internet I have not been able to find a lot of references to this principle.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what is going on in your diagram, but might you be thinking about a kinematic joint?

Comment: Or perhaps a kinematic mount. These constraint two objects with exactly 6 degrees of freedom.